# Invalid date from ISO format JS

Tags: javascript, date

I am getting the ISO date from an API call and this is the format

> "2022-07-19T00:00:00.0000000Z"

when I try to convert this string into a date it gives "invalid date"

```
 var d = new Date(JSON.stringify(response[x]['time_start']));
```

what could be the issue? i tried solutions from similar questions but still no luck, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that is what is happening - `new Date("2022-07-19T00:00:00.0000000Z")` does not return `Invalid Date`?

Comment: Sorry, but why are you trying to JSON.stringify the date string? Json string will not be a valid date, but plain string will be..

Comment: What is the value of `response[x]['time_start']` is it a string? If so why are you trying to convert it to a string?

Comment: @SergeySosunov my bad, i converted string into a string and then tried to make a date, removing json.stringify solves it. thanks a lot, post it as answer so I can accept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per comment answer: just remove JSON.stringify.

```
const dateString = "2022-07-19T00:00:00.0000000Z";
 
// Valid:
const d = new Date(dateString); // Tue Jul 19 2022 03:00:00 GMT+0300 ...

// Invalid:
const jsonDate = JSON.stringify(dateString); // ""2022-07-19T00:00:00.0000000Z""
const d1 = new Date(jsonDate); // Invalid Date
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(response[x]['time_start']))
```

Probably this will not return `"2022-07-19T00:00:00.0000000Z"`.

Comment: I think the problem is that it does log `"2022-07-19T00:00:00.0000000Z"` as it's a string that includes the double quotes which makes it invalid as a date time. `console.log("2022-07-19T00:00:00.0000000Z")` would just log `2022-07-19T00:00:00.0000000Z` without the quotes.

Comment: it was returning "2022-07-19T00:00:00.0000000Z" but with `" "`, should be only 2022-07-19T00:00:00.0000000Z without quotes, removing json.stringify solves it